# Get reference to a generic object<T>

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list, generic-collections

I have objects defined as follows:

```
public class ModelList<T> : ModelBase, IModelList<T>, IModelList 
where T : IModelListItem, new()
{
    public void Method1()
    {
    // do work here!
    }
}

public class Object1 : ModelListItem
{
}

public class Object2 : ModelListItem
{
}

public class Objects1: ModelList<Object1>, IModelList
{
}

public class Objects2: ModelList<Object2>, IModelList
{
}
```

Somewhere in code far far away I have a method that will receive a collection object of either Objects1 or Objects2. Is there a way to call Method1 from here?

```
private void DoSomething(object O)
{
    // O can be either Objects1 or Objects2
    O.Method1();
}
```

Comment: In Java you can check implements c# must have something similar.

Comment: @danny117: I do not think Java's `implements` is related to what the OP is asking for; can you show an example of how you would solve the issue in Java with `implements`?

Comment: In java you can check to see if a class implements an interface.  If it does you can safely call the the implemented method.  Far Far away if you check that the interface is implemented you can safely call the method.

Comment: @danny117: In C#, the `is` operator does the same as the `instanceof` operator in Java that you are referring to. However, distinguishing between several types with `is`/`instanceof` and treating the separately is a rather poor solution when the different types can be handled the same way with some form of polymorphism instead.

Comment: Thanks for the update @O.R.Mapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method does not depend on the type at all, you could add `Method1()` to `IModelList` and pass that in to the function.

```
public interface IModelList 
{
    void Method1();
}
```

used like

```
private void DoSomething(IModelList  o)
{
    // o can be either Objects1 or Objects2 or anything else that implments IModelList
    o.Method1();
}
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but it should be noted that it is only applicable if the OP is in control over `IModelList` and the related types. Given that they say the code they are writing now is "far away", this cannot necessarily be taken for granted.

Comment: Thank you, moving the method to the interface worked GREAT!! Still working on my OOP skill set.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to call Method1 from here?

There is: Make your far away method generic:

```
 private void DoSomething<T>(ModelList<T> o)
   where T : IModelListItem, new()
 {
   o.Method1();
 }
```

Comment: This is probably the way  to go, however I couldn't figure out the syntax to cast Objects1 or Objects2 to the appropriate type when calling this generic DoSomething method.

Comment: @NerdherderEd: There is no need to cast anything. It should work by just passing the item type along: `DoSomething<Object1>(new Objects1());` If you're lucky, the compiler might even be able to infer the type argument, in which case you can skip it: `DoSomething(new Objects1());`

Comment: The method public void WorkOnCollection(object O) works with Objects1 & 2 does not know the type of objects in those collections, they could be collections of either Object1 or Object2. The method call DoSomething(O) causes the inline compiler in VS2015 to bark the message: 'DoSomething<T>(ModelList<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @NerdherderEd: Indeed, the method `DoSomething` does not have to know. Just the code calling the method does.

Comment: Would it be possible to use reflection to cast itself to an object that the DoSomething would accept without barking? Obviously, OOP deficient here.

Comment: @NerdherderEd: Sure, you could retrieve the `MethodInfo` for `DoSomething<T>`, invoke `MakeGenericMethod` while passing `o.GetType()`, and then invoke the typed version of `DoSomething`. However, before doing that, do consider whether the code that handles instances of `Objects1` and `Objects2` really does not know their item type.

Comment: Thanks, being OOP deficient I don't quite understand all that you said. I will have to look that stuff up. Thanks again for taking the time to look at this for me.